# How change file association?

Tags: windows-vista, file-association

I need to change program that opens xml files on my Windows Vista.

When I open "Open With" dialog and click "Browse" and locate my ___.exe, nothing happens.

The program is not added to the list. Vista just ignores my choice.

This exe file is on my D: partition in my DropBox folder. I wonder WTF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[assoc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490865.aspx):** Displays or modifies file name extension associations. Used without parameters, assoc displays a list of all the current file name extension associations.

and

> **[ftype](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490912.aspx)**: Displays or modifies file types used in file name extension associations. Used without parameters, ftype displays the file types that have open command strings defined.

Comment: great I didn't expect these existed

Comment: interesting, didn't known these 2 commands before. now i can change many text file asssociation to notepad2 easily. (.txt .csv .ini .log .conf .sql .c .cpp .h .java .properties .xml .htm .html .css .js .vbs .htc .zul .zs ...)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it will be any more successful, but try right clicking the file,. selecting properties and then hit the change button beside the "opens with" field.

Comment: the same "Open with" dialog pops up.